# in selenium-cucumber-js how to run headless test

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumberjs

I am using [selenium-cucumber-js](https://github.com/john-doherty/selenium-cucumber-js#readme) library 
i have following issues

1. want to check local-Storage in test how Can I do that?
2. Am I able to access the window object?
3. How can run this with Headless?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try something?

Answer (score 0):

1 & 2) This can be done using pure javascript as far as I know. There is a query and it has been responded in the repo [here](https://github.com/john-doherty/selenium-cucumber-js/issues/99).

3) You can replace `start-maximized` with `--headless` in this [line](https://github.com/john-doherty/selenium-cucumber-js/blob/master/runtime/chromeDriver.js#L17).